# java.sql.SQLException: could not use local transaction commit in a global transaction

Tags: java, transactions, sqlexception, distributed-transactions, xa

We are having two instances of oracle *(two physical machines)* and one schema for our application.
we are using weblogic application server. application uses datasource for which XA transaction is enabled.

I am having one bean managed EJB, where i do -

1. update some data in table and then commit
2. submit oracle job
3. again update some data in table and then commit

Here i am getting error - java.sql.SQLException: could not use local transaction commit in a global transaction.

strangely this error is not commig every execution, it is comming 1 in 7-8 executions.

Now my questions are

1. What is significance of bean managed transaction if i use XA enabled transaction ?
2. why it is not encountering in every execution ?

Thanks.

below is code -

```
DataObject.updateDataAndReturnCount(" UPDATE EOD_Trn_BatchProcess SET iJobNo = ?, szParameters = ?  WHERE iProcessSeqNo = ? ", conn, new String[]{null, strParameters, (String)mapParameters.get("__PROCESS_SEQ_NO")});
conn.commit();

String strStatement = "{? = call submitProcAsJob(?, ?)}";
//String strStatement = "begin ? := submitProcAsJob(?, ?); end;";
CallableStatement pStmt = conn.prepareCall(strStatement);
pStmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.NUMBER);
pStmt.setObject(2, strJobName);
pStmt.setObject(3, strInstanceNo);
pStmt.execute();
vString strJobNo = pStmt.getString(1);
vpStmt.close();

DataObject.updateData(" UPDATE EOD_Trn_BatchProcess SET iJobNo = ?, szParameters = ?  WHERE iProcessSeqNo = ? ", conn, new String[]{strJobNo, strParameters, (String)mapParameters.get("__PROCESS_SEQ_NO")});
conn.commit();
```

here first commit is required because i want to save parameters used during call, even if job submission fails.(or any thing ahead.)

Comment: What the transaction attribute?Did you call commit/rollback in your code? Provide you code,that should be more clear

Comment: code added, "transaction attribute" by this do u mean XA datasource configuration ?

Comment: No,in ejb-jar.xml the container-transaction->trans-attribute

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the exception is that you can not mannaully call commit()/rollback under a global transaction,you can only marked it for rollback.You have three options:

1. Throw an exception,which depends on the ejb-jar.xml/weblogic-ejb-jar.xml,the default is for any RuntimeException the transaction is marked for rollback;
2. call the EJBContext.setRollbackOnly() method in case of CheckedException or whenever you need;
3. If none of above happend for all the resouces under the same transaction,it will be commited sooner or later by the transaction manager.

The transaction manager is responsible for commit()/rollback() the transaction for you, so that the it has a chance to co-operate with 
different resources(two oralce db for example).You can check the detail by gooble the key word "two phased transaction" or "global transaction",here is what I found:
[Global Transaction](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A91202_01/901_doc/java.901/a90211/jdbctran.htm#1005396)

As for your question

1. What is significance of bean managed transaction if i use XA enabled transaction ?

   The bean-managed transaction is a "Global transaction" if the transaction-attribute in in ejb-jar.xml enable the transaction propagation. A global transaction need the datasource to be XA enabled,that is the jdbc driver itself is XA kind driver such as oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource ,or the thin driver oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver with XA enabled (a simulation of two phased transaction,but not real one )
2. why it is not encountering in every execution ?

   I am not sure why,I guess the driver have some mechanism to check whether the ruled is breaked.Or the transaction-attribute is configured to ***Supports*** ,so if caller has a transaction context,then your ejb is under global transaction,otherwise not.

I wish my answer to be helpful,good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem,and when I set local transaction to auto commit false solved the problem.

```
Connection.setAutoCommit(false)
```

I guess you are using a 2-phrase transaction,What if you do not commit in you 1st step?

Comment: thanks, i will try this, But do u know why it is not occurring in every execution. Also i need to use commit, because i have to save some data does not matter what happens next.(check point).